# How much Google limits CD2M?

Tags: android-c2dm

The [C2DM documentation](http://code.google.com/intl/es/android/c2dm/index.html#limitations) states that

> Google limits the number of messages a sender sends in aggregate, and the number of messages a sender sends to a specific device

someone knows specifically how much Google limits that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have 2 x C2DM accounts. When I asked what my limit was (for each) they stated 100,000.. That's not 100k / year ? That's 100k per day!

Answer (score 1):

Google doesn't say what their quota is; it probably changes depending on how stressed the service is.

Developers are held to a "development-only" quota, but if you apply for production status, Google will negotiate a specific quota based on how much usage you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the exact number of messages a sender can send to a specific device. But when it expires you will get a lot of "Error=QuotaExceeded" returns from the C2DM server.

But the moderator can increase your message limit by posting your message to the C2DM list.This will take you under one business day I belive.